# Is it possible to transmit data via NFC using APDU commands?

Tags: android, nfc

One potential issue when transmitting data via NFC using APDU commands is related to compatibility and interoperability. NFC (Near Field Communication) and APDU (Application Protocol Data Unit) commands might be supported differently across various devices, operating systems, or NFC-enabled cards.

I tried this:

- **CLA (Class)**: 00 (indicating a standard operation).
- **INS (Instruction)**: D6 (instruction code for Update Binary).
- **P1 (Parameter 1)**: 00 (first parameter).
- **P2 (Parameter 2)**: 00 (second parameter).
- **LC (Length of data)**: 04 (indicating the length of the data to be transmitted).
- **Data:** 686F6C61 (hexadecimal representation of the message "hola").

**The final APDU command: 00D6000004686F6C61**

This command appears to follow the structure of an APDU command, with the header (CLA, INS, P1, P2) and the data to be transmitted (in hexadecimal form). This approach is commonly used to communicate with NFC-enabled devices, such as cards or other NFC-capable hardware.

I had to segment the data in order to send long messages, as it only allowed me to send 9 bytes at a time.

It's essential to ensure that the structure of the APDU command and the data encoding align with the requirements of the receiving device or system to successfully transmit and interpret the information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to transmit data via nfc using apdu commands given the right type of hardware.

The NFC standards specify a number of different hardware standards, some of which use APDU's to communicate to transfer data between hardware.

The NFC standards specify a minimum commands set to be deemed and compliant to the standards, but there is non compliant NFC hardware as well as compliant NFC hardware that have additional commands.

Without more specifics of what you are trying to do it's difficult answer in more detail.